# E-Mail attachment using Sendgird

Tags: python, email, attachment, sendgrid

Basically I want my code to send a E-Mail with a attachment (in this case epub).

Right now I use the sendgrid library for sending mails and to send the attachment to sendgrid, it needs to be base64 encoded and send via post to the sendgrid server.

But since json doesn't support byte type I have to convert the my encoded file to a string. I tried for a long time but have no clue what I do wrong, but I'm fairly certain it has to do with the base64 encoded string.

My code atm looks kind of like this:

```
#Encoding file
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    encoded = base64.b64encode(f.read())

attachment = Attachment()

#Is this done correctly?
attachment.content = str(encoded)

attachment.type = "application/epub+zip"
attachment.filename = filename

email = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
email.add_attachment(attachment)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=email.get())
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Whats your error message and that's not the full code.

Comment: @user1767754 It’s a 400, Bad Request. It’s not all the code but that’s the part that doesn’t work. The rest of the code is irrelevant I pinpointed the mistake to these lines of codes.

Comment: I don't have a test environment, but instead of converting to a string you might try converting it to a bytearray

Comment: @user1767754 A bytearray is not JSON serializable.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for sending e-mails doesn't seem to work when using Python 3. I was also facing this problem. then I found this example [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#attachment)

Replace this line
 `attachment.content = str(encoded)` 
with 
`attachment.content = encoded.decode()`